# Unable to upload a pdf file via POST call in Python

Tags: python, pdf, post, python-requests

I am attempting to upload a PDF file via POST method call in Python. It works perfectly fine via the CURL command but my corresponding python code always gets error as the response from the server. The server-side is implemented in Java.

This is the **curl** command that works fine:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://test.com/files/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ZjQ...' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'pdfDocument=@test.pdf;type=application/pdf'
```

And this is my corresponding python code that does not work:

```
url = 'https://test.com/files/'
bearer_token = 'ZjQ...'
headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {bearer_token}',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}
files = {
        'pdfDocument': open('/path/to/test.pdf', 'rb')
}
response = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)
```

I always get error 500 as the response for this code.

What could be the problem here ? Please suggest!

Comment: It looks like the problem you're facing might be due to how cURL and Python's `requests` library handle multipart/form-data requests. The `Content-Type` header is crucial for multipart requests as it tells the server the type of data being sent.

In your cURL command, you're specifying the content type specifically for the file part of the request using `-F 'pdfDocument=@test.pdf;type=application/pdf'`. However, in your Python code, you're setting the content type for the entire request, which might not be what the server expects.

Comment: Thnx for your reply @IshaanAdarsh 
I understood the point and difference between the 2 requests being sent. But I frankly don't know how to code in python to specify the content type explicitly for the file part (and not entire request). I checked in other related questions in stackoverflow but none seem to be addressing this. Do you have an idea how to do that, I mean code-wise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://test.com/files/'
bearer_token = 'ZjQ...'
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {bearer_token}',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
}

files = {
    'pdfDocument': ('test.pdf', open('/path/to/test.pdf', 'rb'), 'application/pdf')
}

response = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)

# Rest of the code to handle the response
```